# Connection to RDS MySql from ECS Fargate wordpress container times out

Tags: mysql, wordpress, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I have a container running (wordpress container if being more specific), which tries to connect to mysql rds instance.

Parameters for the fargate ecs service container:

```
{ 
    "executionRoleArn": "ignore-this", 
    "containerDefinitions": [ 
        { 
            "name": "MyCoolContainer", 
            "image": "wordpress:latest", 
            "essential": true, 
            "environment": [ 
                {"name": "WORDPRESS_DB_HOST", "value": "host:3306"}, 
                {"name": "WORDPRESS_DB_USER", "value": "user"}, 
                {"name": "WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD", "value": "password"}, 
                {"name": "WORDPRESS_DB_NAME", "value": "name"} 
            ], 
            "portMappings": [ 
                { 
                   "hostPort": 80, 
                   "protocol": "tcp", 
                   "containerPort": 80 
                } 
            ], 
            "logConfiguration": { 
                "logDriver": "awslogs", 
                "options": { 
                    "awslogs-group": "/aws/ecs/fargate/prefix", 
                    "awslogs-region": "eu-west-1", 
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "prefix" 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    ], 
    "requiresCompatibilities": [ 
        "FARGATE" 
    ], 
    "networkMode": "awsvpc", 
    "cpu": "256", 
    "memory": "512", 
    "family": "wordpress" 
}
```

Also, for security groups, I have opened **22**, **80**, **443**, **3306** ports for any IP address.

But the container in ECS still fails to start with the reason:

> [17-Sep-2019 08:42:24 UTC] PHP Warning: mysqli::__construct():
>   (HY000/2002): Connection timed out in Standard input code on line 22
>
> MySQL Connection Error: (2002) Connection timed out
>
> MySQL Connection Error: (2002) Connection timed out

However I can ensure that the RDS instance is accessable, when trying to connect from a local machine with a command:

```
mysql -uuser -ppassword -hhost -P3306
```

Also, I can ensure that a (wordpress) container successfuly runs on local machine and successfully connects to a remote RDS database with no timeouts.

**EDIT**
This is how my environment looks like from ECS UI panel:
(I have tried to copy paste these values into my local mysql command and it connected successfully.)
[image]

I suspect there is something wrong with aws services configuration. Any ideas?

Comment: remove the port from `{"name": "WORDPRESS_DB_HOST", "value": "host:3306"}` and it should work then

Comment: Hi, thank you for a suggestion. However this did not resolve the issue. The connection still timesout.

Comment: I wonder the enviroment variable not set properly. can console the value `WORDPRESS_DB_HOST` so you will able to check in cloudwatch log fargate. The environment variable syantax seem wrong or may be not setting properly

Comment: are you able to ping from fargate? is there any NAT or gateway?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. There is no NAT gateway. Fargate instances sit in public subnets as the RDS instance too. 

Regarding environment varibales set incorrectly - I have edited my post, please see the picture attached. I have tried these values locally and it worked.

Comment: Also, I have deployed a sample container which prints all system environment variables. And indeed the variables were there: {'ECS_CONTAINER_METADATA_URI': 'some-uri', 'AWS_DEFAULT_REGION': 'eu-west-1', 'WERKZEUG_SERVER_FD': '3', 'WERKZEUG_RUN_MAIN': 'true', 'WORDPRESS_DB_HOST': 'some-host', 'HOSTNAME': 'some-hostname', 'AWS_REGION': 'eu-west-1', 'WORDPRESS_DB_NAME': 'the-name', 'WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD': 'the-password', 'WORDPRESS_DB_USER': 'the-user', 'AWS_EXECUTION_ENV': 'AWS_ECS_FARGATE', 'PATH': 'the-path', 'HOME': '/root'}

Comment: I feel completely lost.

Comment: verify one more thing.. is the container able to communicate with outside world?

Comment: Ofcourse haha. I can access it via load-balancer or via directly associated ip address. I have deployed a flask app which returns system environment dictionary on http:://the-ip-address/ call. All the variables are here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199654/discussion-between-adiii-and-laimonas-sutkus).

Comment: @Adiii I have successfully managed to ping external urls and connect to a database from a fargate ecs instance by attaching a NAT Gateway to the subnet in which the instance was!

Comment: This is a super weird architecture contstraint imposed by AWS...

Comment: That's great man finally you did it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Adiii and some other articles found on the internet i have a complete solution to this problem.

You need to simply attach a NAT Gateway to the subnet in which you are launching your ECS Fargate instance.

Simply launching in a public subnet with an Internet Gateway for some weird reason does not solve the problem (even though logically thinking it should).

**TL;DR:**

NAT Gateway is needed. AWS is f****d up.

Comment: One possibility ;) from the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html):`You are charged for creating and using a NAT gateway in your account. NAT gateway hourly usage and data processing rates apply. Amazon EC2 charges for data transfer also apply.`